# Why doesn't apticron ever send me emails?

Tags: apticron

I installed apticron and configured it with a certain email address, but it never seems to send any emails.

Comment: Could you show us your configuration? (Remove any sensitive information, such as your e-mail address!)

Comment: @kraxor My configuration is entirely default, except for the email address value. I've checked and double-checked my email address--it's correct, and contains no special characters.

Comment: Did you check your spam folder?

Comment: Good point, but I've already checked my spam folder.